# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Python 3.7 Deployment Location

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, python-3.7

I'm trying to upgrade an existing application on AWS from the now deprecated Python 3.4 platform to 3.7 with Amazon Linux 2/3.0.1, and in the process I ran into an issue with where the application source code is deployed on the EC2 instance.

From some empirical testing, I found that instead of `/opt/python/current/app` directory that most if not all AWS documentations say (e.g [Troubleshooting issues with the EB CLI - AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli-troubleshooting.html)), with Python 3.7 it is actually deployed in `/var/app/current/`. I wasn't able to find any documentation regarding this change, and it is causing some issues with the application. I'm wondering is there any reason that this change is made? And if it is possible to revert it, how to do so?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess it was due to change from AL1 to AL2? AL2 has brought a lot of changes, such as all new hooks config files and more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the 3.7 Python Elastic Beanstalk distribution uses Amazon Linux 2 which is fundamentally different from the AMI predecessor. If you opt to use Python 3.6 instead you should be able to avoid this issue, as it runs on the earlier Linux version where deployments still occur in /opt/var/app/current. [Most tutorials](https://realpython.com/deploying-a-django-app-and-postgresql-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/) I've found are designed to work with this older rollout, including the [most up-to-date Amazon start guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html#python-django-setup-venv).

If you have the time, try [migrating your code to the newer version](https://scriptreference.com/deploying-django-with-postgresql-on-elastic-beanstalk-and-amazon-linux-2/), as this seems to be the workflow Amazon is embracing going forward, [for all newer versions of Python](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=321653) (such as 3.8 and others yet to come).